# Running psql in Linux Command Line

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, linux

I've just installed Postgres9 and it is up and running without any issues. There is one thing however that is confusing me:

If I type `/usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql test` then postgres command line loads and I can use it as expected, however...

If I `cd /usr/local/pgsql/bin` then type `psql test` I get the following error:

> The program 'psql' is currently not installed.  To run 'psql' please ask your administrator to install the package 'postgresql-client-common'

Does anyone know why? (please don't say install postgresql-client-common as this doesn't solve the problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directory `/usr/local/pgsql/bin` is not in your `PATH` (and neither is `.` - which is a good thing for security reasons). Simply run it like this if you're in that directory:

```
./psql test
```

which says run `psql` from the current directory (`./`).

Comment: Thanks. I don't use Linux very often and always forget basics... which are surprisingly hard to just find the answer to. I should have known this.